# Flutter rebuild / reload image widget when online

Tags: image, flutter, dart, widget

The scenario is like the user started the app offline.
So I am trying to reload the image when the user is back online. but for some wired reason, it doesn't work!

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Image.network('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg'),
          FlatButton(onPressed: () => setState(() {}), child: Text('REFRESH')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You should check the internet connectivity and rebuild the image widget when the internet connected. For this purpose you can use [connectivity](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/connectivity#-readme-tab-) library. Your code should be something like this:

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  var _isInternetConnected=false;

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getConnectivity();
}
  _getConnectivity(){
   try {
    final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
    if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
      print('connected');
      setState(() {
        _isInternetConnected = true;
       });
     }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      print('not connected');
    }
  }

  Widget _showImage(){
    if(_isInternetConnected)
     return Image.network('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg');
   else
     return Image.asset('some image')

  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          __showImage(),
          FlatButton(onPressed: () => setState(() {}), child: Text('REFRESH')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It works though, but I really want to know the reason behind this behavior. Why my code doesn't work?

Comment: @towhid you didnt check for the connectivity changes. beside that `Image.network` will return an error while the internet is not connected.